# Uniform convergence of a parametric integral. Which solution is correct?

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I was given a simple problem on uniform convergence of parametric integrals. The integral was
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx, \qquad a>0
$$
It seems like a straightforward application of the Abel-Dirichlet test. Just to be clear here is my argument.

Set $f(x,a)=\cos(x)$, $g(x,a)=\frac{1}{x+a}$. Clearly

1. There exist $C=2$ such that for any $R>0$ and $a>0$ we have
   $$
   \left|\int_0^R f(x,a)dx\right|<C.
   $$
2. For any $a>0$ the function $g(x,a)$ is strictly decreasing;
3. Since
   $$
   \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sup\limits_{a>0}g(x,a)=0
   $$
   the function $g$ converges to $0$ as $x\to+\infty$ uniformly for $a>0$.

Therefore by the Dirichlet test, the parametric integral $I$ converges uniformly. However, I was told that this is solution is *wrong*.

The official solution says that the integral does not converge uniformly. Itsays that the integral does not converge uniformly "because" even the integral
$$
J(a)=\int_0^{1}\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx, \qquad a>0
$$
does not converge uniformly. Here is a "proof":
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx 
\geq\cos(1)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x+a}dx
=\cos(1)\lim_{s\to +0}\int_{s}^{1}\frac{1}{x+a}dx
$$
Then we claim that
$$
\exists \varepsilon_0\quad
\forall\Delta>0\quad
\exists s_1(\Delta)\quad 
\exists s_2(\Delta)\quad 
\left|\sup_{a>0} 
\int_{s_1(\Delta)}^{s_2\Delta)}
\frac{1}{x+a}dx
\right|
\geq \varepsilon_0
$$
I agree with it. By construction $s_1(\Delta)\in(0,\Delta)$, $s_2(\Delta)\in (0,\Delta)$. Don't forget that fact, we'll recall it later. Finally we claim that
$$
\exists \varepsilon=\varepsilon_0\cos(1)\quad
\forall\tilde{\Delta}>0\quad
\exists \tilde{s}_1(\tilde{\Delta})=s_1(\tilde{\Delta})\quad
\exists \tilde{s}_2(\tilde{\Delta})=s_2(\tilde{\Delta})\quad 
$$
$$
\left|\sup_{a>0} 
\int_{\tilde{s}_1(\tilde{\Delta})}^{\tilde{s}_2(\tilde{\Delta})}
\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx
\right|
\geq \varepsilon
$$
The last statement has an error (imho), because it lacks the requirements $\tilde{s}_1(\tilde{\Delta})>\tilde{\Delta}$, $\tilde{s}_2(\tilde{\Delta})>\tilde{\Delta}$. If you agree with me on this point, then one cannot set $\tilde{s}_1(\tilde{\Delta})=s_1(\tilde{\Delta})$, $\tilde{s}_2(\tilde{\Delta})=s_2(\tilde{\Delta})$ since $s_1(\Delta)\in(0,\Delta)$, $s_2(\Delta)\in (0,\Delta)$. Therefore the official solution is disproving another statement, not the one describing uniform convergence.

**Question 1: Is my solution correct? If not where is a mistake?**

**Question 2: Is my argument against official solution correct? If not, what am I missing?**

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that both solutions are somewhat correct. Your solutions concerns the problem of convergence near $+\infty$, that is by uniform convergence of integral, you mean uniform convergence of family $I_t(a) = \int_0^t \frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx$ as $t \to +\infty$, which indeed, due to Dirichlet test converges uniformly for $a>0$. However, the solution presented on the board seems to adress the issue with uniform convergence of the integrals $J_\delta(a) = \int_\delta^1 \frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}dx$ as $\delta \to 0^+$ which indeed seems to not converge uniformly to $J(a)$

Comment: @DominikKutek, what is the point of considering 0 as a point of singularity if for each fixed a>0 the only singularity of $I$ is $+\infty$?

Comment: because if $a \to 0^+$ then the integrand becomes $\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ which is not integrable near $0$. But in my opinion your solution was more accurate, if there wasn't said anything about $0$, and I'd do it similarly as you did.

Comment: The question of uniform convergence for $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx$ is moot since it is a proper Riemann integral.  Nevertheless, you can examine uniform convergence of either limit: $\lim_{\delta \to 0+}\int_\delta^1$ or $\lim_{\delta \to 0+}\int_0^{1-\delta}$ and the given proof is conflating the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is subtle. Uniform convergence is a condition pertaining to a specific limiting process.

Because the integrand $\frac{\cos x}{x+a}$ is Riemann integrable for each fixed $a > 0$ on any finite interval $[0,K]$, we can focus first on uniform convergence of the improper integral

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_K^R\frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx = \int_K^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx, $$

and extend the conclusion to

$$\int_0^K\frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx +\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_K^R\frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx = \int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx$$

Your application of the Dirichlet test is correct (regardless of $K$) in proving the uniform convergence to this specific limit.  In particular, note that the convergence $g(x,a) = \frac{1}{x+a}\to 0$ is uniform for all $a > 0$ since

$$\sup_{a >0}\frac{1}{x+a} = \frac{1}{x} \underset{x \to \infty}\longrightarrow0$$

**Uniform convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx$**

Since $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx$ exists as a Riemann integral for each fixed $a$ , there is no need to consider an improper integral here and the question of uniform convergence is irrelevant.

Nevertheless, any Riemann integral can be viewed as an improper integral limit since it must hold that

$$\tag{*}\lim_{\delta \to 0+}\int_\delta^1 \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx = \int_0^1  \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx,$$

and we can show that, technically, the convergence for this specific limiting process is not uniform for all $a > 0$.

Note that for all $\Delta \in (0,1)$ and $a_\Delta = \Delta$ we have

$$\left|\int_{\Delta/2}^\Delta\frac{\cos x}{x+a_\Delta} \, dx\right| \geqslant \int_{\Delta/2}^\Delta\frac{\cos1}{\Delta +a_\Delta}\, dx= \frac{\cos 1}{\Delta +\Delta} \frac{\Delta}{2} = \frac{\cos 1}{4} $$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $\Delta \to 0$ we have shown -- by violation of the uniform Cauchy criterion -- that the convergence to the limit in (*) is not uniform for all $a > 0$.

Comment: We can also show that the convergence of $\int_0^{1-\delta} \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx$ as $\delta \to 0+$ is uniform for all $a > 0$ since $\int_{1-\delta}^1 \frac{\cos x}{x+a} \, dx \leqslant \frac{\delta}{1-\delta}$

Comment: @RPL, thank you! The original question was about the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}$), The official argument was that the improper integral does not converge uniformly since neither does the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\cos(x)}{x+a}$. This is what confused me a lot.

Comment: @Norbert: You're welcome.